# Bamboo and perforce integration issue

Tags: integration, perforce, bamboo

I am trying to add perforce repository for bamboo. But not able to make it. Getting following error while adding repository-

I have downloaded latest bamboo 30days trial and installed on my local machine. Bamboo is installed correctly as I am able to create automated build using MSBuild with BitBucket repository.

My bamboo instance is running on http://localhost:8085.

I have Downloaded and installed latest P4D and P4V from https://www.perforce.com/downloads and installed in the same machine. Perforce server and client are correctly configured as I am able to checkin source code to server using client. Running on  port 1666. By client and server are both installed in C:\Program Files\Perforce.

[image]

I have added bamboo Server Capabilities for perforce.

[image]

On providing perforce detail while adding repository, getting following three alerts from p4v client-

[image]

User id and password are correct also url with port is correct. I am able to get data from repository with this detail.

p4v.exe is already there in my PATH and also I run p4v -help on command prompt, getting following result. I dont see any option named 'info'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4v.exe` is the GUI program for Perforce.

There is a command-line program for Perforce, called `p4.exe`.

When Bamboo says that it wants `The location of the p4 client executable`, you have to specify the path to `p4.exe`, not the path to `p4v.exe`.

When you downloaded and instlaled `p4v.exe` on your system, you should also have received a `p4.exe` (if not, download that program, too). Then specify the path to `p4.exe` to Bamboo.

Comment: I have changed server capabilities to p4.exe. Now I dont see any error popup. But getting following message for Depot view-

"Depot view is not in the format //client_name/... or //client_name/workspace_mapping/..."

Comment: If I run p4 info, getting the following-

C:\Windows\System32>p4 info
User name: bamboo
Client name: QS-0049
Client host: QS-0049
Client root: c:\Users\adas
Current directory: c:\Windows\System32
Peer address: 127.0.0.1:60081
Client address: 127.0.0.1
Server address: QS-0049.Portal01.nextgen.com:1672
Server root: C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server
Server date: 2018/06/21 16:09:31 +0530 India Standard Time
Server uptime: 00:28:32
Server version: P4D/NTX64/2018.1/1660568 (2018/05/09)
Server license: none
Case Handling: insensitive

Comment: My depot view looks like - //depot/JsonToClassGenerator/

Comment: I tried many combinations-

//depot/JsonToClassGenerator/

//QS-0049/JsonToClassGenerator/

//QS-0049/depot/JsonToClassGenerator/

Comment: You might want to post a new question so people don't need to try to explain client views to you in this terribly cramped "comment" format.  :)